# android surfaceView onTouchListener

Tags: android, surfaceview, ontouchlistener

I want to add an OnTouchListener to my surfaceView but I can't quite get it.
I tried to add the OnTouchListener in the MainActivity with

```
surfaceView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

without result. Any suggestions?

Main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.surface_view);      
    surfaceView= (AnimationSurface) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
}
```

SurfaceView

```
public class AnimationSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

SurfaceHolder Holder;
Thread Thread = null;
boolean isRunning = true;
float x=0;
float y=0;

public AnimationSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
    Holder = getHolder();
    Thread = new Thread(AnimationSurface.this);
    Thread.start();     
}


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    [...]

    }
}
```

Thanks for your time,
Maldita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use **onTouchEvent** within surfaceview